# Complex numbers like a factor ring $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}[t]/(t^2 + 1)\mathbb{R}[t]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

At a lecture about factor rings the lecturer gave us the following example:

$$\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}[t]/(t^2 + 1)\mathbb{R}[t]$$

He said that it was quite obvious and skipped the explanation. But it is not obvious for me at all and I have some questions:

1. How could $(t^2 + 1)\mathbb{R}[t]$ be imagined? Does it mean that we put $(t^2 + 1)$ as an argument to any $f \in \mathbb{R}[t]$? I mean the set - $\left \{ f(t^2 + 1) | f \in \mathbb{R}[t]\right \}$.
2. And if I am right in the first guess then how does the factor ring look like?

I can understand what e.g. $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$ is but it is very confusing when this is about polynomials.

Comment: $(t^2+1)\mathbb{R}[t]$ is the ideal generated by $t^2+1$; that is, the collection of polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[t]$ that are divisible by $t^2+1$. Given that, the factor ring can be visualized by setting $t^2+1=0$ in $\mathbb{R}[t]$; that is, setting $t^2 = -1$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: You can think of the quotient $(t^2+1)$ as requiring $t$ to have square -1 in $\mathbb{R}[t]$, hence you can construct an isomorphism to $\mathbb{C}$ by mapping $t$ to $i$

Comment: @XuqiangQin I think you can post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What your professor wrote, though I have to say that notation is awful from personal taste, is the ideal
   $$\langle t^2+1\rangle=(t^2+1)\mathbb{R}[t]=\{p(t^2+1): p\in\mathbb{R}[t]\}$$
   that is the set of all polynomials that is a multiple of $t^2+1$, so no you are not correct thinking it is the arguement.
2. It looks like this $at+b + I$ with $I=\langle t^2+1\rangle$, any polynomial of grade $2$ or higher will be able to factored into a multiple of $t^2+1$ with some rest of lesser grade, which is our $at+b$. This can be shown to be isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$ by the homomorphism $\varphi(at+b+I)=ai+b$

Answer (score 0):

There is a  unique surjective ring homomorphism ${\bf R}[t] \to \bf C$ which send $t$ to $i$. The kernel of this homomorphism is exactly the set of real polynomials with $i$ as a root. This is exactly the polynomials dividible by $1+t^2$, or ${\bf R} [t].(1+t^2)$